# How to store $.getJSON object in global variable and navigate through it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm experimenting with JQuery and trying to create a function to get dynamic data from a JSON returned API and store it in a global variable (I don't know if this is the right/best way to do this).

What I have so far is

```
function getdata(url){
    var data = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
    });
    return data;
};
```

So far everything works fine, but this returns an object with a "responseJSON" key and I can't seem to find a way to navigate to this key and then do a $.each loop through the arrays in it.

So the questions are:

1. Is this the right / way ( if not please explain your answer)
2. How do you navigate through a multidimensional object containing arrays in the "responseJSON" key.

Comment: What you are doing will work, if and only if *later* is a time that is guaranteed to be ***after*** the ajax request has completed. My assumption would be that that isn't the case. Can you give a more complete example, showing what *"later"* means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to pass a callback to your function so you can set the response handler within the function and less code when you call your getData method

```
function getdata(url, callback){
    var data = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url
            }).done(callback).error(function(){
               alert('Oppps...something went wrong')
            });
    return data;
};


getData('urlstring', function(data){
   /* doSomething with data */
})
```

Comment: Nice part is you left in the return, so you can still use the promise.

Comment: @KevinB pretty flexible pattern that I like too

Answer (score 3):

AJAX is *asynchronous*.  That means it runs in the background while the rest of your script runs.  At a point in the future when the AJAX call completes, then you can access it.

In jQuery, `$.ajax` returns a promise.  So what you can do is the following:

```
getdata('/path/to/your.json').done(function(data){
    // Use your JSON data here
    console.log(data);
});
```

What happens is that once the AJAX call is done, your `.done()` function will run and you will have access to the data returned.

Don't try to access the properties of the `$.ajax` object (the `responseJSON` won't be populated until the call is finished).  Use callbacks to get at the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the json data to be in global scope, just define a global variable (that is, outside the function), and then in the function fill it with the returned data. Something like so:

```
var api_response;

function get_data(url) {
  $.post(url, function(j) { api_response = j; }, "json");
  // or
  $.getJSON(url, function(j) { api_response = j; });
}
```

You don't even need to create a function for this and can use jquery's own $.getJSON (the *or* case).

Comment: problem with this approach is you don't know when or if it has been returned to global variable. Not always the best place to start when learning

Comment: @charlietfl yes, I agree. But it could be used for certain cases. I usually use global variables like so for caching the returned data (when I know it remains unchanged for the session) to avoid multiple calls.