# oo practice, make function not hard coding, return data after bind change

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to find a way,give a dom as parameter and get data, from image_preview. 
and separate `image_preview.model()` and `image_preivew.on_chage()` is event handler

**make image_preview reusable not hardcode inside**
I espect I will call `image_preview` pass dom in parameter, and return src as response ,  then I can use repsponse do something like append ...

```
  var image_preview = {
    on_change: function(wrap_dom, input_dom) {
      $(wrap_dom).on('change', input_dom, function(event) {  // I have to use on change because there are possible the `input dom` is new append... 
        var el_obj = $(this)[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();

        var file_length = el_obj.files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
          form_data.append("file[]", el_obj.files[i]);
        }

        image_preview.model(form_data).done(function(response) {
          // console.log(response); // this is work
          return response;
        });
      });
    },
    model: function(form_data) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: uri_public+'/admin/ajax/preview_file',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // async: false
      });
    }
  }


  var app_thumbnail = {
    preview_controller: function() {
      var wrap_dom = '.thumbnail';
      var input_dom = '.upload-form input';
      var result = image_preview.on_change(wrap_dom, input_dom);
      // pass result to render view like append dom....
    },
    render: function() {

    },
  }

  app_thumbnail.preview_controller();
```

Comment: This is a very common question. Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: consume the response within the `done` callback

Comment: @kurideja thanks for reply, I saw that before but I'm stuck I can't return after done function in `on_change()`

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me some example code

Comment: what are you expecting to do with response? If you want to parse it to html for example you would do it in the done callback...right where your logging works

Comment: @charlietfl  response is image src I will wrap it with img tag and append

Comment: simple enough, forget the `return` right after the console.log and append the image there instead

Comment: @charlietfl  but I tried to let this function can use anywhere I espect I will call `image_preview` give dom, and get src  and append in `app_thumbnail.preview_controller()`   or other function maybe `app_gallery.preview_controller()` ...

Comment: can also do something like `image_preview.model(form_data, myImageHandler)` and add the `done` to `$.ajax` in the model

Comment: see if this idea helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611949/how-to-store-getjson-object-in-global-variable-and-navigating-through-it-later/27612027#27612027

Comment: I get it now you are trying to use `model` as a service. good luck!

Comment: @charlietfl yes! I tried to let `bind event` and `model` as each function in one object `image_preview`, than I can only pass dom then return data do something in other controller like append/render ..I name this like view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest thing you can do:

```
  var image_preview = {
    on_change: function(wrap_dom, input_dom) {
      $(wrap_dom).on('change', input_dom, function(event) {
        var el_obj = $(this)[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();

        var file_length = el_obj.files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
          form_data.append("file[]", el_obj.files[i]);
        }

        image_preview.model(form_data).done(function(response) {
          app_thumbnail.preview_controller(response);
        });
      });
    },
    model: function(form_data) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: uri_public+'/admin/ajax/preview_file',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // async: false
      });
    }
  }

  var app_thumbnail = {
    preview_controller: function(response) {
      var wrap_dom = '.thumbnail';
      var input_dom = '.upload-form input';
      var result = response;
    }
  }

  // If you want to initialize it.
  // image_preview.on_change(..., ...);
```

Comment: mmm.... this way still have to hardcode in `image_preview.on_change() ` call `app_thumbnail.preview_controller(response);` or other future function, totally not what I espect to looking for

Comment: I cannot give you a better answer without knowing what you want to do in your `preview_controller`. Moreover, you should explain in your question what you want to say in your comment: "*or other future function, totally not what I espect to looking for*".

Comment: I want to find a way,give a dom as parameter and get data, from image_preview.

Comment: What you want to do (ie. `var result = image_preview.on_change(wrap_dom, input_dom);`) cannot work because you ask for a synchronous return whereas you have an asynchronous return with AJAX (ie. when you get the return in `result` the AJAX request is processing and has no response yet). You have to pass a callback to handle that (that will be executed when the response will be there). I gave you the easiest way. I cannot give you a better option without clearly understanding the architecture you want to make.

Comment: Glad if I could help you understand it.